# A function to conduct post hoc chisquare goodness of fit test in R?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, post-hoc

I have this vector of frequency values

```
x = c(100,400,500,600,700)
```

when conducting chi square test goodness of fit I have this result that has a global significative p value

```
chisq.test(x)
```

However I am looking for a posthoc test function in R that can tell me which values are significantly different from each other and the values that are not.

Comment: You seem to need some statistical advice. You should ask for help at [stats.se] instead to decide what type of test to use.  This doesn't seem like a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not about the test. I am just looking for the suitable function in R that can make this test.

Comment: What test do you want this function to perform? It doesn't seem to make sense to compare just two numbers and ask if they are statistically different. Is 3 different from 4? What assumptions are you making in order to make that decision.

Comment: The default reference group of comparison in chisq.test function is usually the equal probabilities calculated in this case as 100% /5 = 20%. and we compare it with the probabilities of each value in the vector. But the problem is that chisquare gives a global p value. And my employer is looking for which exact values are significantly difference from each other. Eventhough I never heard of something like that, I decided to post my question here in case something like that exists as a function in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of methods come to mind.

First, to load the packages and data:

```
if(!require(DescTools)){install.packages("DescTools")}

x = c(100,400,500,600,700)

chisq.test(x)

chisq.test(x)$expected

   ### [1] 460 460 460 460 460
```

First, you could examine the standardized residuals. These can be interpreted, for example, that a standardized residual of < -1.96 or > 1.96 suggests that that cell is significantly different than the expected value at *alpha* = 0.05.

```
STDRES = chisq.test(x)$stdres

STDRES

   ### -18.766297  -3.127716   2.085144   7.298004  12.510865
```

And to convert these to *p*-values:

```
signif((pnorm(abs(STDRES), lower.tail=FALSE)*2),3)

    ### 1.42e-78 1.76e-03 3.71e-02 2.92e-13 6.51e-36
```

Another approach is construct multinomial confidence intervals.

One use would be to consider those categories whose confidence intervals don't overlap would be significantly different from one another.

Another use would be to consider those categories whose confidence intervals don't include the expected proportion (0.2 in this case) to be significantly different from the expected value.

These proportions could be converted to counts, simply by multiply them by `sum(x)`.

```
library(DescTools)

MultinomCI(x, conf.level=0.95, method="sisonglaz")

   ###  est     lwr.ci     upr.ci
   ### [1,] 0.04347826 0.02173913 0.06525062
   ### [2,] 0.17391304 0.15217391 0.19568541
   ### [3,] 0.21739130 0.19565217 0.23916367
   ### [4,] 0.26086957 0.23913043 0.28264193
   ### [5,] 0.30434783 0.28260870 0.32612019
```

With the caveat that I am the author, some further examples and discussion can be found at: [Summary and Analysis of Extension Program Evaluation in R](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help.